# When a question is moved, change its styling to match that site on the original

Tags: feature-request, migration

Let's say a question is asked on SO and it's voted to be closed and moved to SU. That leaves you with an empty question. Why not provide some visual cue as to what's happened to it? The easiest way to do that is to change it's appearance.

That could be as simple as changing the "X votes, 0 answers" box to be styled like the destination site. It could go even further but I think that one box is enough.

Comment: Titles don't really need to end with a period.

Comment: Neither do comments

Comment: @random: You are going to debate an edit because I used a period? Are you serious?

Comment: Not really, but you could do with a nice little interrobang there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe have an additional banner just below the title sporting a little note, something like:

> [[image: Super Tiny User] This question can now be found at Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/21767/setting-a-default-cpu-frequency-in-ubuntu)

and the icon of the new home site just to not be so harsh.

Comment: I would vote you up since I like your idea, but answers don't need to end in a period.

Comment: @Random - I like the icon idea - we need the text to be a bit more salient though so it looks more "finished"

Comment: This whole answer was a fractured sentence‽

Comment: Your image is broken, @random. I tried editing the URL to use `i.imgur`, `stack.imgur` and `i.stack.imgur` but none of them worked.

Comment: Well bugger that. Will have to see if it's on the harddrive somewhere. @pop

Comment: In hindsight, it's not surprising; this was before the SE Pro Imgur account existed.